# How to get rid of appended li in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to disable an `li` element with `id="magic-line"` when someone resizes the window below 640 pixel width. Is there an easy way to do that?

Code:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() >= 640){
        $(function() {
            var $el, leftPos, newWidth;
            $("#example-one").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
            /* Cache it */
            var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");
            $magicLine
            .width($(".current_page_item").width())
            .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
            .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
            .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());
            $("#example-one li").find("a").hover(function() {
                $el = $(this);
                leftPos = $el.position().left;
                newWidth = $el.parent().width();

                $magicLine.stop().animate({
                    left: leftPos,
                    width: newWidth
                });
            }, function() {
                $magicLine.stop().animate({
                    left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                    width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
                });    
            });
        });
    }
    else if($(window).width() < 640){


    }
});
```

Comment: In the future, it is better to ask a question related to something you've done rather than something you haven't done.

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing it with css?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #magic-line {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#magic-line").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Can't really get it to work $( window ).resize(function() { this line also completly messes up the animation

Answer (score -1):

Presuming your $ refers to jQuery,

```
$("#magic-line").hide();
```

should do it.

Update: you can't disable an LI tag, so here I'm suggesting just hiding it. If you had a click event attached, you could check if it should proceed in the event handler.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean jQuery?